# MySQL and PHPmyAdmin gives different results on same query

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2

I have to find the max date in a certain table in my database.
This table is updated every night before midnight so the max date should be yesterday.
if I run this query:

```
SELECT MAX(`date_insert`) as max FROM `alive_probability`
```

in PHPMyAdmin I get the yesterday date, which is correct, if I run the same query in my node.js code I get the day before yesterday.

I've looked for similar questions and the web it's full of similar issues but I wasn't able to find a solution or a reason for my issue

I'm using the npm module "mysql2" and that's my javascript code

```
let contollSQL = "SELECT MAX(`date_insert`) as max FROM `alive_probability`";
let db = await connection.connetti()
let controllo =  await db.execute(contollSQL);
let ieri = dash.getIeri();
let cont;
let toCheck;
cont = JSON.stringify(controllo[0][0].max);
cont = cont.split("T")
toCheck = (cont[0].split("\""))[1]
console.log(controllo)
console.log(toCheck)
console.log(ieri)
if(toCheck == ieri){
    res.send("OK")
}else{
    res.send("ERROR")
}
```

Here the database connection code

```
const connetti = async ()=>{
const cn=await mysql.createConnection({
    host:   ***,
    user: ***,
    password: ***,
    database: ***,
    Promise: bluebird
    });
    
    return cn;
}
```

Comment: Look at your queries. They are different

Comment: Sure i've translated the name of the queries to make it easier to understand, my database have Italian columns name, let me edit the question,

Comment: Test does ```SELECT CAST(MAX(date_insert) AS CHAR(19)) as max FROM alive_probability``` will produce equal outputs.

Comment: Thanks @Akina it works. Can you explain me why?

Comment: Your query produces datetime value. The connector and software which transfers this data to final client (framework, for example) adjusts this value according to timezone info which results in decreasing the date part. My query converts the datetime value to string type, and none timezone adjustments are applied to it, so you receive the value produced by SQL without any modification. of course my query is a palliative, you must set your timezone settings correctly.

Comment: Ok perfect explanation, thanks a lot